# ActiveRecord transitive association deletion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following model:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :providers, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :products, :through => :providers
end

class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :products, :inverse_of => :provider
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :provider, :inverse_of => :products
end
```

When I create an organization with a provider (and no products) and then delete it with destroy:

```
Organization.find(1).destroy
```

Rails 3.0.x **does NOT** delete the associated provider leaving non-existing organization_id. This is weird behavior, I'd expect either nil there or the provider to be deleted (that's what I want to do).

I see there is transitive association has_many :products :through => :providers - I wonder if this is the reason why provider is not deleted.

Thanks for any help

Edit:

Ok this has nothing to do with Rails, we have the following check in the Provider class

```
  def prevent_redhat_deletion
    if redhat_provider?
      errors.add(:base, _("Red Hat provider can not be deleted"))
      return false
    end
    true
  end
```

and obviously I was deleting a redhat_provider one. For some reason, Rails won't exit with an error.

Comment: What underlying database are you using?  And can you post the SQL that runs when calling `destroy`?  The models look correct, more likely this is data related...

Comment: PostgreSQL. I only see this: AREL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "organizations" WHERE "organizations"."id" = 4 (and COMMIT on the next line). Organization is removed via delayed_jobs, but this is not important. The delete SQL statement is simple. Btw the code is here - https://github.com/Katello/katello/blob/master/src/app/models/organization.rb

Comment: Btw the delete AR statement is: Organization.unscoped.find(123).destroy and it's done in a different process. But when I try it from console, I have the same.

Comment: The only thing I see out of the ordinary, is that you have overridden the `Provider#organization` method to not return an association proxy.  I'm not sure if this matters at all, but can you try again after commenting that code out?  Also, before the SQL `DELETE` statement, there should be several `SELECT` queries that run to collect all dependent associations - are you seeing this at all, and specifically for `providers`?

Comment: Will try, in the mean time here is the log: http://pastie.org/private/hp5m0oqk8w6orpmtznqaq and big thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

What you can also try, is changing the :dependent = :destroy, to :dependent => :delete.  See if the providers get deleted.  If they do, its probably something with your code thats preventing the deletion.